# Optimize MySQL query with subqueries, IF and Joins

Tags: mysql

I've a complex SQL Statemant which needs per call (its for a calender view) **0.35sec**. With 50 users and a 2 weeks of calender items, it takes 245sec which is much too long. I tried to optimize the query but at the moment I've no more idea.

I've an index on all related columns.

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT tax.ta_id, tax.a_id, ax.status, ax.kunden_id, 
      IF(ax.todo_from != '0000-00-00', DATE_FORMAT(ax.todo_from, '%d.%m'), 'k. day_date') todo_from, 
      IF(ax.todo_until != '0000-00-00', DATE_FORMAT(ax.todo_until, '%d.%m'), 'k. day_date') todo_until, 
      IF((SELECT taj.city FROM suborders taj WHERE taj.a_id = tax.a_id AND taj.order_type = 'BRING' ORDER BY pos_id ASC LIMIT 1) != '', CONCAT(IF((SELECT short_name FROM locations WHERE company_id = '100' AND h_id = tax.h_id) != '', (SELECT short_name FROM locations WHERE company_id = '100' AND h_id = tax.h_id),tax.city),'>', CONCAT((SELECT IF((SELECT short_name FROM locations WHERE company_id = '100' AND h_id = taj.h_id) != '', (SELECT short_name FROM locations WHERE company_id = '100' AND h_id = taj.h_id), taj.city) FROM suborders taj WHERE taj.a_id = tax.a_id AND taj.order_type = 'BRING' AND taj.pos_id >= tax.pos_id ORDER BY pos_id ASC LIMIT 1))), IF((SELECT short_name FROM locations WHERE company_id = '100' AND h_id = tax.h_id) != '', (SELECT short_name FROM locations WHERE company_id = '100' AND h_id = tax.h_id),tax.city)) as city, 
  tax.user_id, tax.day_date, tax.pos_gesamt_id, '4' as class_type 
    FROM 
      suborders tax INNER JOIN orders ax ON (ax.a_id = tax.a_id) 
    WHERE 
      tax.order_type = 'TAKE' AND tax.user_id = '140' AND (tax.day_date = '2013-04-16' AND '2013-04-16' = (SELECT taj.day_date FROM suborders taj WHERE taj.a_id = tax.a_id AND taj.user_id = '140' AND taj.day_date = '2013-04-16' AND taj.user_id = '140' AND taj.order_type = 'BRING' ORDER BY pos_gesamt_id ASC)) AND tax.company_id = '100' GROUP BY tax.ta_id
```

Maybe you give me some recommendation.

Comment: do you have composed indexes too?

Comment: no, how would that help? which columns should this index include?

Comment: You have a LOT of correlated subqueries and these are all likely to perform poorly. I am trying for work out quite how you are getting the city field to try and recode that

Comment: You would be likely to receive more answers if you explained a bit what your query is supposed to do, if you explained the structure of your tables, and if you showed an example of the expected result. As it currently stands, your query is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

First attempt at a rewrite (untested, as I have no idea of your table layouts):-

```
SELECT DISTINCT tax.ta_id, tax.a_id, ax.status, ax.kunden_id, 
      IF(ax.todo_from != '0000-00-00', DATE_FORMAT(ax.todo_from, '%d.%m'), 'k. day_date') todo_from, 
      IF(ax.todo_until != '0000-00-00', DATE_FORMAT(ax.todo_until, '%d.%m'), 'k. day_date') todo_until, 
      IF((SELECT taj.city FROM suborders taj WHERE taj.a_id = tax.a_id AND taj.order_type = 'BRING' ORDER BY pos_id ASC LIMIT 1) != '', 
        CONCAT(
            IF(Sub2.short_name != '', Sub2.short_name,tax.city),
            '>', 
            CONCAT((
                SELECT IF(  Sub3.short_name != '', 
                            Sub3.short_name, 
                            taj.city) 
                FROM suborders taj 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT h_id, short_name FROM locations WHERE company_id = '100') Sub3 ON Sub3.h_id = taj.h_id
                WHERE taj.a_id = tax.a_id 
                AND taj.order_type = 'BRING' 
                AND taj.pos_id >= tax.pos_id 
                ORDER BY pos_id 
                ASC LIMIT 1))), 
            IF(Sub2.short_name != '', Sub2.short_name, tax.city)) as city, 
  tax.user_id, tax.day_date, tax.pos_gesamt_id, '4' as class_type 
FROM suborders tax 
INNER JOIN orders ax ON (ax.a_id = tax.a_id) 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT a_id 
    FROM suborders taj 
    WHERE taj.user_id = '140' 
    AND taj.day_date = '2013-04-16' 
    AND taj.user_id = '140' 
    AND taj.order_type = 'BRING' 
) Sub4 ON Sub4.a_id = tax.a_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT h_id, short_name FROM locations WHERE company_id = '100') Sub2 ON Sub2.h_id = tax.h_id
 WHERE tax.order_type = 'TAKE' 
 AND tax.user_id = '140' 
 AND tax.day_date = '2013-04-16' 
 AND tax.company_id = '100' 
 GROUP BY tax.ta_id
```

At this stage I am not sure I can go any further with this, as it is REALLY confusing me how things fit together.

The problem is you have a lot of correlated subqueries and these are slow (ie, a sub query that relies on a field from outside the query - hence MySQL has to perform that subquery for every single line). I have removed a couple of these that I can work out and replaced them with joins to subqueries (with these MySQL can perform the subquery once and then join the results to the main query)

But it is very confusing when you have correlated subqueries within queries, and you have reused alias names between different tables and subqueries.

The query can be greatly improved in performance if I can work out what it is meant to be doing!

Further you also have used GROUP BY on the main query without any aggregate columns. This is sometimes done instead of a DISTINCT, but you have a DISTINCT as well.